# Python multiply sequence trick

Tags: python, list, sequence

the trick is:

```
IPython prompt:

In [1]: A = [ [] ] * 2

In [2]: A
Out[2]: [[], []]

In [3]: A[0].append(1)

In [4]: A
Out[4]: [[1], [1]]
```

Obvious, it's not my expected result, what's I want is `[[1], []]`. So why? I found no ref in the docs about python multiply sequence.

And is there any elegant(use no any explicit loop) ways to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A = [ [] ] * 2` creates a list with two references to the *same* list:

```
>>> A = [ [] ] * 2
>>> id(A[0])
24956880
>>> id(A[1])
24956880
>>> id(A[0]) == id(A[1])
True
>>>
```

Instead, you need to use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> A = [[] for _ in xrange(2)]
>>> A
[[], []]
>>> A[0].append(1)
>>> A
[[1], []]
>>>
```

Note that, if you are on Python 3.x, you will need to replace `xrange` with `range`.

Answer (score 2):

`[ [] ]` is an array containing (a reference to) a list. When you multiply it by 2, you get a list containing two references to the *same* list. Try this:

```
A = [[] for i in range(5)]
```

It will generate a new empty list for every tick of `range`.

There can't really be a no-loop version of this, because you really need to construct multiple lists; there can be no shortcut.

Comment: No problem.  I'm glad you've updated the answer though.  :)

Comment: The correction was good, but we really don't need to see the crossed-out old version - it's distracting.

Comment: He retracted the comments because you fixed the problem. I'll do the same if you want. If your own comments seem out of place now you can delete those yourself.